# My app is not on the Google Play store,can I get it to auto update?

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

I have recently finished developing an Android application that does not qualify to be on Google Play store because it does not target a certain SDK. the app will be downloaded directly from my website, but I also want it to support automatically checking for and downloading updates.
is there a proper way to achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to implement the update criteria from scratch. Well on app open you can check with your server if there is an update, you do this by comparing the version on the server with your versionCode if the version on your server is greater than the version code in your app then you have an update. You can ask then the user to download the apk file, if the user accepts you download the file and use the below snippet to install it.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE, uriOfDownloadedApk);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uriOfDownloadedApk, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are free to implement an own update mechanic which checks the current app version and compares it with the latest version on your server.

Alternatively, you can check out one of the existing app distribution solutions like Microsoft Appcenter. This allows you to use the Appcenter SDK which can check at each start of the app, if the user uses the latest version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/android

Comment: Thanks! I tried MS's SDK but I'm afraid the new version gets distributed to a select group of users, like testers. I'm not sure this is the most efficient way to do it when there's a large number of users of the app since you have to add the users individually as destinations of the distribution.

Comment: @WalidBaroudi You can also define Teams and Distribution groups once and reuse them for each new version.

Comment: that's true but we won't be keeping track of individual users, however we want everyone who has the app to get updates. I'm afraid that's not doable with this SDK.